# Any way to update an existing record zone to allow zone sharing?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, sharing, ckrecordzone

First-time poster here who writes apps as a hobby, so thanks in advance for your understanding of any shortcomings I may have in either this post or my Cloudkit knowledge.

I have an app that created a record zone in the private database and shared data using the record-hierarchy method with one parent record at the top and all other records as children. I would now like to update it to use zone sharing, and have successfully removed all parent/child relationships and deleted the parent record.

When I try to save the zone share record I get an error code 12 with the message "share type inconsistent with zone capabilities". If I try to save the share record via UICloudSharingController, I get a console message that says I must save the share before I can access it.

My existing zone shows a capabilities value of 7. If I create a new zone, it has a capabilities value of 15. I haven't figured out how to get deeper into it and haven't found anything in the documentation, but I'm assuming that the difference is the zone sharing capability.

Is there a way to add the zone sharing capability to my existing zone? Or do I need to create a new zone and move all of the existing data to that zone before implementing zone sharing?